# Xcode 6.3.1: iOS 8.4 - The Developer Disk Image could not be mounted

Tags: ios, image, disk

I have updated the xcode to the latest version 6.4 but when I try to check the version in About xcode window it is showing as 6.3.1. Currently i'm running the latest iOS 8.4 version on my device. Can anyone one tell me why am I getting the **The Developer Disk Image could not be mounted (iPhone 5S may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode)** error when I try to build the ios application on my device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue!